# Increasing array elements while in foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, php-internals

Consider the code below:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
   print "key=>$key\n";
   if(!isset($arr['a']))
      $arr['a'] = 'apple';
}
?>
```

It is not displaying 'a'. How foreach works with hash-table(array), to traverse each element. If lists are implement why can't I add more at run time ?

Please don't tell me that I could do this task with numeric based index with help of counting.

Comment: "It is not displaying 'a'", what do you mean?

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bzacR3)

Comment: @Rikesh: please find it [here](http://ideone.com/1qkleX)

Comment: @Rikesh see stdout section

Answer (score 3):

Foreach copies structure of array before looping([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)), so you cannot change structure of array and wait for new elements inside loop. You could use `while` instead of `foreach`.

```
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';

reset($arr);
while ($val = current($arr))
    {
    print "key=".key($arr).PHP_EOL;
    if (!isset($arr['a']))
        $arr['a'] = 'apple';
    next($arr);
    }
```

Or use `ArrayIterator` with foreach, because ArrayIterator is not an array.

```
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';

$array_iterator = new ArrayIterator($arr);


foreach($array_iterator as $key=>$val) {
   print "key=>$key\n";
   if(!isset($array_iterator['a']))
      $array_iterator['a'] = 'apple';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store array element continue sly

**Try**

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
   print "key=>$key\n";
   if(!isset($arr['a']))
      $arr['a'][] = 'apple';
}
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

You will get values.

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
   print "key=>$key\n";
   if(!isset($arr['a']))
      $arr['a'] = 'apple';
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
key=>b
<pre>Array
(
    [b] => book
    [a] => apple
)
```

Comment: Pl accept so others will get help from this ....

Comment: Did you read the question? It is: _why adding new key had no effect __during loop__ (not how to output array)_

Comment: please read the question once again

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check key exist or not in array use `array_key_exists` function

Eg:

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';
print_r($arr);          // prints Array ( [b] => book ) 
if(!array_key_exists("a",$arr))
      $arr['a'] = 'apple';
print_r($arr);         // prints Array ( [b] => book [a] => apple )
?>
```

If you want to use `isset` condition try like this:

```
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';
$flag = 0;
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
   print "key=>$key\n";
   if(!isset($arr["a"]))
   {
        $flag = 1;
   }
}
if(flag)
{
     $arr['a'] = 'apple';
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: you need not to check even, try removing isset check and then run

Answer (score -1):

How about using for and realtime array_keys()?

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr['b'] = 'book';

for ($x=0;$x<count($arr); $x++) {
   $keys = array_keys($arr);
   $key = $keys[$x];
   print "key=>$key\n";
   if(!isset($arr['a']))
      $arr['a'] = 'apple';
}
```